# How to append a <script> to <body> using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, document-body

I've read roughly 8 different questions here on StackOverflow about this same issue. I've tried a handful of different approaches, most of which involve creating the script element and then adding attributes to it, finalizing by `join`, `append()`, `appendTo`, `document.body.appendChild`, etc.

I cannot get this script tag to show up before `</body>`.

Script I need to append to `<body>`:

```
<script src="http://ib.adnxs.com/seg?add=1448379&t=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's some marketing pixel I need to add to a site that's CMS generated. It has to show up only on ONE page based on the `document.location.pathname`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
$("body").append($("<script>", {  src : "http://ib.adnxs.com/seg?add=1448379&t=1",  type : "text/javascript" }))
```

Comment: Silly question, Have you imported jquery?

Comment: Yup. Working with a CMS. The page is generated, hence why I have to inject new stuff with jQuery and the like. All of the core stuff, like jquery and libraries, is built into the CMS and is all baked right in.

Comment: No frames or iframes. After repeated failures, I wound up having to consult with the back-end engineers who built the CMS. They worked out a solution that involved tweaking this site's CMS template. Big thanks for offering your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
$("<script"+ " src"+"\="+ "http:\//ib.adnxs.com\/seg\?add=1448379&t=1"+" type"+"="+"text\/javascript"+"></script>").appendTo($("body"));
```

add \ to escape special characters

appendTo() will append just before end of body tag

**Console**

[image]

**HTML**

[image]

Comment: Using that gave me 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' in Chrome dev tools console.

Comment: Have you copied correctly. Because according to me it is working fine. I'll paste an image of it

Comment: Don't try on jsfiddle because it won't allow any  script tag. Do one I've recently tested this on jquery.com. Working fine. Just go on that site open console and run. It won't create problem